# Rails Password returns nil if blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im kind of new to rails and i'm not using devise. My problem is that when i use password_field in my form for my password and i update only the subscriber_number, the password becomes blank in my database. but when i use a text_field for my password, the actual value can be seen and saved. this is what i'm trying to do:

```
class EdiUser < ActiveRecord::Base

validates_presence_of :subscriber_number
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create

end
```

and in my controller:

```
    def update
            @trader_edi_user = TraderEdiUser.find(params[:id])
            @edi_user = EdiUser.find(@trader_edi_user.edi_user_id)
            #@edi_user.update_attributes(edi_user_params)

            if params[:edi_user][:password].blank? == true

              @edi_user.update_attributes(edi_user_subscriber_number) 
            else
                @edi_user.update_attributes(edi_user_params)
            end
        redirect_to :back
    end

 private
        def edi_user_params
            params.require(:edi_user).permit(:id, :subscriber_number, :password, :password_confirmation)
        end

        def edi_user_subscriber_number
            params.require(:edi_user).permit(:subscriber_number)
        end
```

and this is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@edi_user, url: {controller: 'maintenance/edi_users', action: 'update'}, html: {class: "form-horizontal", id: "edit_edi"}) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group edi subs">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label has-feedback">Subscriber Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
           <%= f.text_field :subscriber_number, :class => "form-control req", :required => 'true', :id => "subscriber" %>
           <br>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group edi pass">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label has-feedback">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
           <%#= f.text_field :password, :class => "form-control", :id => "password", :minlength => 6 %>
           <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "form-control", :id => "password" %>
           <br>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group edi confirm_pass">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label has-feedback">Confirm Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
           <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => "form-control", :id => "confirm_password", data: { :match => "#password"} %>
           <br>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
           <div class="pull-right">
              <%= button_tag type: "submit", class: "btn btn-md btn-success raised pull-right", id: "update_btn2" do %>
                   <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> <%= t('Button.Update') %> 
              <% end %>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
<% end %>
```

is my code for my update action on my controller wrong? or is there something i'm missing?

thank you very much in advance

Comment: Just to be sure..... Please tell me you're not storing the password in plain text?!

Comment: nope. i'm using attr_encrypted to store my password

Comment: The `user_name` is not in your form nor in your code, how do you update it?

Comment: sorry, typo error. it should've been subscriber_number

Comment: Have you considered the built-in [`has_secure_password`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html)? It allows you to set the password via `password=`, but returns `nil` when attempting to retrieve `password` (the actual hash digest is stored as `password_digest`). This way, it doesn't interfere with your form.

Answer (score 0):

You can reject blank params,

```
def update
  @trader_edi_user = TraderEdiUser.find(params[:id])
  @edi_user = EdiUser.find(@trader_edi_user.edi_user_id)
  edi_user_params.reject! {|k, v| v.blank?}

  if @edi_user.update_attributes(edi_user_params)
    # Success
  else
    # Error
  end
  redirect_to :back
end

private

def edi_user_params
  params.require(:edi_user).permit(:id, :subscriber_number, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

I would still advise you to use something like Devise for security reasons.

Comment: may i know what is the meaning of this code?
edi_user_params.reject! {|k, v| v == ""}

Comment: i'm having this error

undefined method `reject!' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Your edi_user_params is nil. You need to keep your strong parameters. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Add following line to the first line of your method may slove your question

```
redirect_to password_blank_path if edi_user_params[:password].blank?
```

However, here are some advice for your code

```
@trader_edi_user = TraderEdiUser.find(params[:id])
@edi_user = EdiUser.find(@trader_edi_user.edi_user_id)
@edi_user.update_attributes(edi_user_params)
```

Permitting params before using it

Recommand to using relationship between two models

Using find_by instead of find, cause find may raise exception if nothing found

```
# assuming TraderEdiUser belongs_to :edi_user
@trader_edi_user = TraderEdiUser.find_by(id: edi_user_params[:id])
@trader_edi_user.edi_user.update_attributes(edi_user_params) if @trader_edi_user.present?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
# edi_user.rb
validates :password, presence: true, if: :should_validate?

def should_validate?
  new_record? # other condition you could put here
end
```

How about this regarding your controller:

```
def update
  @trader_edi_user = TraderEdiUser.find(params[:id])
  @edi_user = EdiUser.find(@trader_edi_user.edi_user_id)
  if @edi_user.update(edi_user_params)
    redirect_to some_where_path
  else
    redirect_to elsewhere_path
  end
end

private

def edi_user_params
  params.require(:edi_user).permit(:id, :subscriber_number, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```